# warning: Semantic Issue: Incompatible pointer types initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'NSString *'

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

I am trying to do the following:

```
NSString *personDesc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Person named %@", person.name];
char *myArguments[] = { personDesc, NULL };
```

But it is producing this error:

```
warning: Semantic Issue: Incompatible pointer types initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'NSString *'
```

The reason I am trying to convert the NSString into a char is because I am passing `myArguments` into `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges`

e.g.

```
AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges(auth, tool, kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, myArguments, NULL);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As matt said above, you need to convert the `NSString` to a `char*` before you can do what you want. Try something like:

```
NSStringEncoding stringEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding;
NSString *personDesc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Person named %@", person.name];
const char *cPersonDesc = [personDesc cStringUsingEncoding:stringEncoding];
char *myArguments[] = { cPersonDesc, NULL };

// auth and tool already exist
AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges(auth, tool, kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, myArguments, NULL);
```

Comment: When I tried this code I received this warning when assigning `cPersonDesc` to `myArguments`: `warning: Semantic Issue: Initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'const char *' discards qualifiers`

Comment: See the BetterAuthorizationSample example code; they specifically talk about this problem. Basically you just have to cast away `const` (i.e. cast to `char*`) to calm the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

It's right. NSString is not char*. It is NSString. They have nothing to do with one another.

Since you give no indication of what you're really trying to do, no further advice can be given. You could convert NSString to char* if you wanted to, e.g. with `getCString:maxLength:encoding:`. But why would you want to?

Comment: Sorry, but you are absolutely right regarding my lack of information. Please see the updates